# Passing id returned by outer function to inner function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a nested function within an event handler.  The outer function creates a copy of a document from the Trees collection.  The inner function then creates copies of any documents from the Branches collection whose ids are included in an array in the `treeBranches` field of the original tree document.

I need to pass `newTreeId` from the outer function to the inner function, so that the new branch ids can be added to the array in the new document.  `console.log(newTreeID)` in the inner function is currently returning undefined.

```
Template.Actions.events({
    'change .action-selection': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selection = $(e.target).val();
        var currentTreeId = this._id;
        var branches = Branches.find({_id:{$in:this.treeBranches}});

        switch(selection) {
            case "repeat":
                return Meteor.call('treeRepeat', currentTreeId, function (newTreeId) {
                    branches.forEach(function(b) {
                        var currentBranchId = b._id;
                        console.log(newTreeId);
                        Meteor.call('treeBranchesRepeat', currentBranchId, newTreeId, function () {
                        });
                    });
                });
                break;
                ...

Meteor.methods({
    treeRepeat: function(currentTreeId) {
        check(currentTreeId, String);

        var tree = Trees.findOne({_id:currentTreeId}, {fields:{_id:0, treeBranches:0}});
        var newTreeId = Trees.insert(tree);

        return {
            _id: newTreeId
        };
    },
    treeBranchesRepeat: function(currentBranchId, newTreeId) {
        check(currentBranchId, String);
        check(newTreeId, String);

        var branch = Branches.findOne({_id:currentBranchId}, {fields: {_id: 0}});
        var newBranchId = Branches.insert(branch);
        Trees.update({_id:newTreeId},{$push:{treeBranches:newBranchId}});

        return {
            _id: newBranchId
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this could be simplified by performing all duplications of the tree and branches all at a single request to the server. Suggesting the following workflow (not tested, but I think you get the idea):

```
Template.Actions.events({
    'change .action-selection': function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var selection = $(e.target).val();
        var currentTreeId = this._id;
        var currentTreebranches = this.treeBranches;

        switch(selection) {
            case "repeat":
                return Meteor.call('treeAllRepeat', currentTreeId, currentTreebranches, function (err, res) {
                  if (err) { console.log(err); }

                  console.log(res); // Your new tree _id
                });
                break;
                ...

Meteor.methods({
    treeAllRepeat: function(currentTreeId, branchIds) {
        check(currentTreeId, String);
        check(branchIds, [String]);

        var tree = Trees.findOne({ _id: currentTreeId }, { fields: { _id: 0, treeBranches: 0 } });

        if (!tree) {
          throw new Error('Tree with id ' + currentTreeId + ' not found');
        }

        var newTreeId = Trees.insert(tree);
        var branches = Branches.find({ _id: { $in: branchIds || [] } });

        branches.forEach(function (branch) {
          var newBranch = Branches.findOne({ _id: branch._id }, { fields: { _id: 0 } });
          var newBranchId = Branches.insert(newBranch);
          Trees.update({ _id: newTreeId }, { $push: { treeBranches: newBranchId } });
        });

        return {
          _id: newTreeId
        };
    }
});
```

I assume `this.treeBranches` is the ids of the branches? If not, you probably want to do something like:

```
var currentTreebranches = _.pluck(this.treeBranches, '_id');
```

PS. Remember t subscribe to the new tree, if you have removed the `autopublish` package.

Comment: Bjorn, thanks very much!  This works great.  My inexperience often makes me overcomplicate things.

Comment: Good luck with your journey with Meteor :)